# How can I allow users to overwrite the numbers in the input type number (when there are already two numbers)?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Please see the JavaScript below:

```
maxLengthDay(event) {
    const maxLength = 2;
    if (event.target.value.length + 1 > maxLength)
      return false;
    else
      return true;
  }
```

and the HTML below:

```
<input (keypress)="maxLengthDay($event)" type="number" />
```

It works as expected i.e. it ensures the input box only contains two characters at most.  The problem occurs if the user highlights the number (specifically when there are two numbers) and try to overwrite one or two numbers.  Nothing happens because the input control contains two numbers at that point.

How can I allow users to overwrite the numbers in the input control (when there are already two numbers)?

Comment: are the minimum and maximum attributes not available to you?

Comment: Why use JavaScript at all? https://jsfiddle.net/xksb7o0p/

Comment: @Turnip, it is a number field.

Comment: @w0051977 Very good point. I will clean my glasses.

Comment: @Matt Ellen, if I specify a max of: 99 then I can still enter 100 or above into the input field.

Comment: @Turnip, thanks.  Is there any other way of approaching this?

Comment: In plain JS, I'd maybe do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/vyjtdcLq/

Comment: @Turnip your example accepts any negative number -32323123

Comment: Another check for `-99` or `0`, whatever the minimum, could easily be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, you could add a handler with timeout that will allow user to continue entering values, but retain only last entered 2 digits.

For snippet to work, below example is pure JS based.  It can be extended to be used in Angular code as well.

```js
function maxLengthDay(event) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const maxLength = 2;
    if (event.target.value.length + 1 > maxLength) {
      var v = event.target.value;
      event.target.value = event.target.value.substr(v.length - 2, v.length);
    }
  }, 0);
}

document.addEventListener('keypress', maxLengthDay);
document.addEventListener('paste', maxLengthDay);
```

```html
<input  type="number" />
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you put timeout for 1 ms and not 0 ? Also this wont work if you copy paste in a value , use `input` instead of `keypress`

Comment: @dota2pro We can use 0 as well.  For copy/paste - it was not part of original question, but we can fix it by adding handler for "paste" event

Comment: Thanks.  I have only just seen this.  +1 for the reference to paste.  This did the trick for me.  Are you able to look at my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077369/paste-event-to-exclude-numbers

Answer (score 4):

I would set the `min` and `max` properties and then check the validity of the number on input, and set anything out of bounds to either the max or the min.

```js
document.getElementById('num').addEventListener('input', function(e)
{
  if(e.target.validity.rangeOverflow)
  {
    e.target.value = e.target.max;
  }
  if(e.target.validity.rangeUnderflow)
  {
    e.target.value = e.target.min;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" min="0" max="99" id="num">
```

Comment: You need to use the `input` event rather than `keyup` otherwise right-click -> paste will allow out-of-range numbers.

Comment: This is a good answer but I don't think it satisfies the question if you hold 2 and enter 222 it will change it to 99 everytime

Comment: @dota2pro the problem in the question seems to be the ability to select and overwrite whatever's in the number box. This allows that, plus bounds checking.

Comment: Hmm as far I understood he want to implement `maxlength` property for input type number

Comment: @dota2pro to quote: "How can I allow users to overwrite the numbers in the input control (when there are already two numbers)?"

Answer (score 1):

From what I have read in the comments I have changed `keypress` to `input` because of the paste to the input box.

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="99" (input)="maxLengthDay($event)">
```

The input is restricted to values between 0 and 99 but that works only for the increment and decrement arrows. It can also be used to determine whether the value has **overflow** the **max** value or **underflow** the **min** value

If the value is **over** then it just slice the first two numbers and use them as a value.

If it's **under** then it's set the **min** as value.

```
maxLengthDay(event) {
  if(event.target.validity.rangeOverflow) {
    event.target.value = event.target.value.slice(0, 2);
  }
  if(event.target.validity.rangeUnderflow) {
    event.target.value = event.target.min;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for use of min and max.  Are you able to look at my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077369/paste-event-to-exclude-numbers