# Why does a directive have to be added to a HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Please see my directive below:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[text]'
})
export class TextDirective {

  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event) {

      var inputValue = event.which;
      if (!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 120) && (inputValue != 32 && inputValue != 0) && inputValue != 45 && inputValue != 8 && inputValue != 46) //{ //https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/
        event.preventDefault();   
  }
}
```

It is used here:

```
<input text maxlength="50" class="form-control form-input" type="text" placeholder="Surname" [formControl]="newPersonForm.controls['surname']">
```

The TextDirective is called correctly.  However, it is also called here:

```
<input class="form-control form-input" type="number" placeholder="Age" [formControl]="newPersonForm.controls['age']">
```

The age input tag does not contain the textControl directive.  Why is it called?

If a HostListener works in the same way as an Event Listener (for all input controls), then what is the point in adding the textControl directive to the input tag.  All the webpages I have read (like this one: https://alligator.io/angular/hostbinding-hostlistener/) suggest you have to.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the keyword document from the `@HostListener()` decorator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you bind to keydown event on the whole document.
Just remove the keyword `document` from the `@HostListener`

Directive code would look like this

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[text]'
})
export class TextDirective {

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event) {
    // The function code
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way in JavaScript to detect if text is being overwritten in an input box? I am trying to get the potential value after the change is made in the keydown.

Comment: The only way that comes on my mind if I understand you well. Save length of the value and then check if it's higher or lower.

Comment: But the length in the keydown is the length before the change is made? How do you get the value after the change is made.  I asked a question about it yesterday if you could answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060494/how-can-i-allow-users-to-overwrite-the-numbers-in-the-input-control-when-there

Comment: Are you able to use keypress instead?

Comment: keypress does not detect when the deletion key is pressed so I have the same problem.

Comment: You just need to trigger  the function when some character from value was removed?

Comment: Are you able to answer my other question with an example as I don't know what you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207263/discussion-between-josef-katic-and-w0051977).